# VLC: Video works in stream, but not in the saved file

Tags: video, video-streaming, mp4, vlc

I'm trying to stream my Blackmagic Intensity Shuttle to an HTTP-stream and a file.

I use this code on the command line to run VLC:

```
"E:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" dshow://  :dshow-vdev="Decklink Video Capture" :dshow-adev="Lijningang (Blackmagic Audio)"  :live-caching=300 :dshow-fps=25 :decklink-mode=pal :dshow-chroma=UYVY --sout-keep --sout #transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=F:\\\\video\\\\test.mp4,no-overwrite},dst=http{mux=ts,dst=:8181/}, dst=display} :sout-keep
```

When I open the HTTP-stream audio and video are both working. But I see a black screen (audio works) when I open the file.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Did you ever get help/solutions to this question?

Comment: No, unfortunately not..